Jerking Text While animation in Android Jetpack Compose
both are video links , text is shaking while swing animation
video link
video link First Check the video , in Video u can see Text is jerking or shaking , i don't want this type of shaking in text, i want smooth animation without shaking text, i also use text over image and canvas also but not working

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.animation.core.FastOutSlowInEasing
import androidx.compose.animation.core.RepeatMode
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloat
import androidx.compose.animation.core.infiniteRepeatable
import androidx.compose.animation.core.rememberInfiniteTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.rotate
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.TransformOrigin
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.graphicsLayer
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import network.chaintech.testapplication.ui.theme.TestApplicationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
enableEdgeToEdge()
setContent {
Swing()
}
}
}

@Composable
fun Swing() {
Box(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
) {
Panel()
Nail(Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
}
}

@Composable
fun Panel() {
val angleOffset = 10f
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
val angle by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
initialValue = -angleOffset,
targetValue = angleOffset,
animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
animation = tween(
durationMillis = 4000,
easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
),
repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse,
), label = ""
)

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .rotate(angle),
        color = Color.Red,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello, Jetpack",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)
            )
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun Nail(modifier: Modifier) {
Surface(
modifier = modifier
.padding(top = 2.dp)
.size(32.dp),
color = Color.Red,
shape = CircleShape,
border = BorderStroke(width = 8.dp, color = Color.White)
) {}
}


Please format your code correctly. Also pease don't add video links, but attach the video directly here in stack overflow. (You might need to convert its format). This provides a smoother user experience and decouples this question from the availability of some third party site

@m.reiter It is only possible to upload a gif directly here, and with the framerate of a gif, the shaking of the text is not going to be visible at all.

Try replacing rotate modifier with this graphicsLayer modifier:
.graphicsLayer {
    rotationZ = angle
    compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
},

CompositingStrategy.Offscreen means that:

Rendering of content will always be rendered into an offscreen buffer first ...

So the text will be drawn before rotation.

@IshantSharma Please mark this answer as accepted answer then by clicking the checkmark at the left side of this answer.
